# No enclosing instance of type is accessible

Tags: java

I wrote this Java interface program in Eclipse, but there is a red line under **MyTriangle tmp = new MyTriangle();** and when i run the program I get this error:

> No enclosing instance of type Question1 is accessible. Must qualify
>   the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Question1 (e.g.
>   x.new A() where x is an instance of Question1).

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
     MyTriangle tmp = new MyTriangle();
     tmp.getSides();
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("The area of the triangle is " + tmp.computeArea());
     }

interface Triangle
{
 public void triangle();
 public void iniTriangle(int side1, int side2, int side3);
 public void setSides(int side1, int side2, int side3);
 public void getSides();
 public String typeOfTriangle(); 
 public double computeArea();            
}

 class MyTriangle implements Triangle
 {
  private int side1,side2,side3;
  public  void triangle()
  {
    this.side1 = 3;
    this.side2 = 4;
    this.side3 = 5;
  } 
}
```

Comment: This isn't your whole program, and I suspect that it's all contained inside a single file and class named `Question1`, correct?

Comment: You're defining a bunch of methods in your interface that you're not implementing in the subclass.

Comment: that is not my entire program. and correct! everything is in Question1.java

Comment: Please work on your oops concepts. Your code has other defects.

Comment: try my second part of code and let me know if it fixes your issue, Really wondering why it is voted down

Comment: im wondering the same. thats what i was looking for. Thank you! all i needed was to do this: MyTriangle tmp =  new Question1().new MyTriangle();

Comment: Downvoted because the source code in the question is invalid. The `Question1` class mentioned in the error message is not provided.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this. Removed the methods for simplicity

```
public class Test1 {     

    public static void main( String [] args) 
    { 
        MyTriangle h1 = new MyTriangle();     
    } 
} 
class MyTriangle implements Triangle{
    int side1;
    int side2;
    int side3;

    public MyTriangle(){
        this.side1 = 1;
        this.side2 = 2;
        this.side3 = 3;
    }
}
interface Triangle{}
```

---

You have not pasted your full code, I assume your code should look something like below.

Then you should create the Instance for your main class before creating instance for your triangle as shown below

```
public class Test{
     class MyTriangle 
     {
      int side1,side2,side3;
      public   MyTriangle()
      {
        this.side1 = 3;
        this.side2 = 4;
        this.side3 = 5;
      } 

    }
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
     MyTriangle h1 = new Test(). new MyTriangle();   // Fix is here**   
     }
}

interface Triangle{}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is all i needed: MyTriangle tmp =  new Question1().new MyTriangle();

Answer (score 21):

`MyTriangle` is a non-static inner class. That means like all other instance members it (& it's instance) belongs to an instance of the outer class as opposed to the class itself. Remember to belong to a class things need to be defined as `static`.

Hence, you need to provide an outer class instance to instantiate the inner one as

```
new OuterClass().new MyTriangle();
```

If you mark the inner class `static` which makes it *nested* it would allow you to refer to it in a static context like a public static `main()` method.