# Error in AsyncTask with parameters

Tags: android, button, android-asynctask, onclick, android-context

I'm trying to create an `AsyncTask` with `Context` as parameter `onClick` of a `button` of a `Alert`.

But I am getting the error:

> No enclosing instance of type is accessible Alerts. Must Qualify the
>   allocation With An enclosing instance of type Alerts (egxnew A ()
>   where x is an instance of alerts).

**Alertas.java**

```
public static void alertaHorarios(final Context context, final PerfilObj perfil)  {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alerta, null);       
    builder.setView(v);

    sonidos(context);

    cargarAlerta(context,
            v, 
            R.drawable.iconodescargar, 
            "Descargar datos", 
            "¿Desea descargar de internet los datos (horarios y tarifas) de " +
                    "<font color='" + 
                    context.getResources().getColor(Modulo.cargarColorAplicacion(context, perfil.getColor())) + "'><b>" + 
                    context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) + "</b></font>?",
            perfil.getColor());

    builder.setPositiveButton("Descargar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            Modulo.reproducirSonidos(context, perfil.getSonidos(), sound, sonidoBoton);

            tareaAsincronaInicio task = new tareaAsincronaInicio(context, perfil);
            task.execute();

        }});
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            Modulo.reproducirSonidos(context, perfil.getSonidos(), sound, sonidoBoton);
        }
    });      

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.show();

    Button b = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);

    if(b != null) {
            b.setBackgroundResource(COLOR_FONDO_BOTONES);
            b.setTextSize(TAMANO_FUENTE_BOTONES);
            b.setTypeface(Modulo.fontPrincipal(context));
            b.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColorStateList(COLOR_FUENTE_BOTONES));
    }

    Button b2 = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
    if(b2 != null) {
        b2.setBackgroundResource(COLOR_FONDO_BOTONES);
        b2.setTextSize(TAMANO_FUENTE_BOTONES);
        b2.setTypeface(Modulo.fontPrincipal(context));
        b2.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColorStateList(COLOR_FUENTE_BOTONES));
    }
}

private class tareaAsincronaInicio extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {

            private Context mContext;
            private PerfilObj perfilObj;

            public tareaAsincronaInicio (Context context, PerfilObj perfil){
                 mContext = context;
                 perfilObj = perfil;
            }

...
}
```

Comment: where is context initialized?

Comment: onClick is in a method and it has context as parameter

Comment: use `YourActivityName.this` instead

Comment: I have a class Alerts with many methods with differents alerts. In a alert onClick I call a AsyncTask

Comment: You need a context. ActivityContext. You need to pass that.

Comment: where do you call `alertaHorarios`

Comment: @Raghunandan in BaseActivity extends FragmentActivity with Alertas.alertaHorarios(this, perfilObj);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690770/no-enclosing-instance-of-type-is-accessible

Answer (score 0):

If the AsyncTask code is written inside the Fragment/Activity as an inner class it is better to use YourActivityName.this instead of the context as Raghunandan commented.

If the code is is written outside the Activity/Fragment you can either use the BaseApplicition context cause if you use the Activity context might leak the activity. This can happen when the activity close's before the task is finished.

Comment: I have edited my code. Alertas class not is Activity/Fragment

Answer (score 0):

Just use YourActivityName.this instead of passing the context to the AsyncTask.