# No closing instance error with Java when combining classes

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime-error

I am trying to put my separate Java files in 1 class. It looks like this.

```
public class oneClass {
    class Request {
        public double a;
        public double b;
        public double c;

        public Request(double a, double b, double c) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
        }
    }

    public static class Controller {
        public static void main(String[] args) {   
            Request req = new Request(time, 0, 0);

            // some code
        }
    }
}
```

but I ran into an error

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:      No enclosing instance of type oneClass is accessible. Must
>   qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type problem2
>   (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of problem2).

What's going on?

Comment: Use `static class Requst` instead of `class Request`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No enclosing instance of type is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690770/no-enclosing-instance-of-type-is-accessible)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `Request` a static class if you want to construct it outside an instance of your outer class.